# How did gggqG format the file?

Tags: textwidth

I have set textwidth in `.vimrc`:

```
set tw=80
```

Format the sample file with `gggqG`:

```
test
=======================
::

    words_en = ['exercitationem', 'perferendis', 'perspiciatis', 'laborum', 'eveniet',
    'sunt', 'iure', 'nam', 'nobis', 'eum', 'cum', 'officiis', 'excepturi',
    'odio', 'consectetur', 'quasi', 'aut', 'quisquam', 'vel', 'eligendi']
```

It is converted into the following format:

```
test ======================= ::

    words_en = ['exercitationem', 'perferendis', 'perspiciatis', 'laborum',
'eveniet', 'sunt', 'iure', 'nam', 'nobis', 'eum', 'cum', 'officiis',
'excepturi', 'odio', 'consectetur', 'quasi', 'aut', 'quisquam', 'vel',
'eligendi']
```

Why can't be formatted as the below?

```
test 
======================= 
::

    words_en = ['exercitationem', 'perferendis', 'perspiciatis', 'laborum',
'eveniet', 'sunt', 'iure', 'nam', 'nobis', 'eum', 'cum', 'officiis',
'excepturi', 'odio', 'consectetur', 'quasi', 'aut', 'quisquam', 'vel',
'eligendi']
```

Comment: well, you told Vim to format the whole file. How should Vim know, that for the very first 3 lines, it should keep the lines and not put it into a single line? Because that's what you tell it with your textwidth setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the internal formatting routine (`formatprg` and `formatexpr` are empty), then how the text is formatted depends on the value of `:help 'formatoptions'`:

```
:set fo?
  formatoptions=tcq
```

With the default value, Vim will try to join every line until it reaches `textwidth`. If you don't want that, you can add `w`:

```
:set fo+=w
```

which tells Vim to consider each line that ends with a non-whitespace character as a paragraph and thus to not attempt to join it with the surrounding lines. See `:help fo-table`.

But do you really want that behavior all the time? If not, do you really want to change the option before and after the formatting? Maybe a different approach is worth considering?

`gggqG` is not a random sequence of characters to learn in isolation. It actually is a sequence of two commands:

- `gg` is a motion that puts the cursor on line 1,
- `gqG` is an operator, `gq`, applied to the text covered by a motion, `G`, which moves the cursor to the last line.

Therefore, a literal translation of `gggqG` would be:

> "move the cursor to the first line and then format the text from there to the last line"

which really means:

> "format the whole buffer"

You shouldn't be surprised if Vim does what you ask it to do.

If you don't want to format the whole buffer, then there is no reason to ask Vim to do that.

If you want to format the text from a specific line, say line 5, to the last line, the proper command would be:

```
5GgqG
```

where `5G` moves the cursor to line 5 and `gqG` formats the text from there to the last line.

If you want to format the text from the current line to the last line, the first part, where you move the cursor to the first line you want to format, is unnecessary so the proper command would be:

```
gqG
```

where `gqG` formats the text from the current line to the last line.

If you want to format the text between line 5 and line 25, the proper command would be:

```
5Ggq25G
```

where `5G` moves the cursor to line 5 and `gq25G` formats the text from there to line 25.

Of course, you can use any motion for the initial positioning and for the operator:

```
?foo<CR>gq'k
```

moves the cursor to the first `foo` before the cursor and then formats the text from there to mark `k`.

You can even forgo the initial positioning and use a text object for `gq` if that suits your needs better:

```
gqip
```

See `:help gg`, `:help gq`, `:help G`, `:help ?`, `:help '`, and `:help ip`.